# c# web-client login out

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

this is my code that allows me to log in, now i need something to make them logout

```
{
   Tracker.TrackerLogout();
   Response.Write("all logged out");
   //Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

but am getting the error "got a problem ....."

Comment: Why did you delete most of your question? This is not helpful to others who will be searching for a similar question later on.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything to "log out" of these websites. You are not "logged in" in any meaningful sense. The `WebClient.DownloadString` method simply pulls the contents of a URL without making you "logged in."

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i am logged in from other code from the site, but as this is the root site, how can i log out of all 3

Comment: That question is impossible to answer with so little information.